# Using Angular Controllers with prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my question is really simple.

It is possible use Angular Controllers with prototype?

```
'use strict';
var EventController = function(scope, EventModel) {
    this.scope      = scope;
    this.EventModel = EventModel;
};

EventController.prototype = {
    create: function() {
        this.scope.create = function() {
            this.EventModel.Model.insert()
                .then(function(result) {

                });
        };
    },

    retrieve: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.EventModel.Model.find()
            .then(function(result) {
                that.scope.events = result;

            });
    },

    retrieveOne: function(id) {
        this.EventModel.Model.findOne(id)
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);

            });
    },

    update: function() {
        this.EventModel.Model.update()
            .then(function(result) {

            });
    },

    delete: function() {
        this.EventModel.Model.remove()
            .then(function(result) {

            });
    }
};

module.exports = function(adminApp) {
    adminApp
        .controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'EventModel', function(scope, EventModel) {
            return new EventController(scope, EventModel);

        }]);
};
```

I'm using Browserify, that's why i have this module.exports in the final.

I would love to use controllers that way and get the methods as if it were the name of the objects in the prototype.

There is any way that i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can. Here's a demo I've produced using similar code to yours.

**The magic of this is in the "Controller as" syntax, which was introduced in Angular 1.2.0.**

There are three buttons in the demo. One uses the prototype methods on the controller itself, as you asked for, and the other two illustrate that you can continue to use the controller as you're probably used to, by using the scope entirely in the markup, and by supplying scope methods in the controller.

https://jsfiddle.net/scarl3tt/3copx1rk/1/

## Javascript

```
'use strict';
var TestController = function(scope) {
    this.scope      = scope;
};

TestController.prototype = {
    doAThing: function() {
        alert('This is a thing');
    }
};

angular.module('testApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
        if(typeof(scope.extension) === 'undefined')
            scope.extension = function() {
                scope.j *= 2;
            };
        return new TestController(scope);
    }]);
```

## Markup

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl" ng-init="i = 0; j = 1;">
    <h1>Controller as:</h1>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.doAThing()">Do a thing!</button>
    <h1>Scope:</h1>
    <button ng-click="i=i+1">i == {{i}}</button>
    <h1>Extension method using scope</h1>
    <button ng-click="extension()">j == {{j}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Can i ask for more information? How did this work behind the scenes? i didn't understood the scope.j *=2;

Comment: That's a very contrived way of illustrating two points. The fact that the method works shows that you can add scope methods (notice that it wasn't invoked through `ctrl`). The actual `scope.j *= 2;` line shows that you can manipulate scope variables as normal (there specifically it's multiplying `j` by 2). None of that is really relevant to your original question, but just showing that the `Controller as` syntax gives you flexibility to work with `scope` as you had to prior to 1.2. The important parts for you are `ng-controller="TestController as ctrl"` and `ng-click="ctrl.doAThing()"`.